# Create a function to extract filenames from multiple filenames using delimiter in bash

Tags: bash, filename

e.g.,report jpg will display about all the files that are called something.jpg.
Here's a code I'm working on including my questions.

```
function report {
        x=`ls *.$1`
        num=`ls *.$1 | wc -l`  
        # Question 1:
        # Want to use variable for x to get
        # num, but num=$($x | wc -l) didn't work for this purpose.
        echo There are $num $1 files
        if [ $num -lt 10 ]; then
            # Question 2:
            # for this part, I want to use "find . -name '*.$1' 
            # with delimiter . to extract filename from its extension 
            # and display them (Also maybe need to use while or for loop)              
        fi
}
report jpg
report html
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include examples of what you are trying to do - it's hard to understand what *"extract filenames from multiple filenames using delimiter"* means without a few examples

Comment: FYI your whole approach falls into [Bash Pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

report(){

    local -a n=(*.$1)
    echo "There are #${#n[@]} files in '$PWD' with extension '$1'."

    if (( ${#n[@]} < 10 )); then
        find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.$1" -printf %f\\n | sed -e 's/\.[^.]*$//'
    fi
}

report $1
```

Usage: ./script.sh jpg

Comment: inspired by @steeldriver not to use 'ls' in script anymore, there are just too many pitfalls

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions specifically:

Q1. the expression `$x | wc -l` means "run the command `$x` and pipe the results to `wc -l`". To pipe the *contents* of `$x` to `wc`, you could use `` num=`echo "$x" | wc -l` `` or (using a bash [here string](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Heredocs_And_Herestrings)) `` num=`wc -l <<< "$x"` ``.

However the "backtick" form of command substitution is deprecated - better to get into the habit of using `$( ... )` i.e.

```
num=$(wc -l <<< "$x")
```

Note that this will give the wrong count if any filenames contain newline characters (which they are allowed to in Linux).

Q2. In `find . -name '*.$1'`, the single quotes (aka 'hard quotes') around `'*.$1'` will prevent expansion of `$1` so `find` will search for filenames ending literally in `$1`. To allow expansion of `$1` while preventing premature expansion of `*.`, use double quotes (aka "soft quotes") i.e. `"*.$1"`

You will probably want to limit the search to the top-level directory rather than descending into subdirectories (else the results will be inconsistent with the count obtained from `wc`):

```
    find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.$1"
```

---

**However**, here's how I'd do it - assuming a `bash` shell:

```
report() {
  shopt -s nullglob
  local ext="$1"
  set -- *."$ext"
  printf 'There are %d %s files' $# "$ext"
  if (( $# > 0 && $# < 10 )); then 
    printf '\t%s\n' "$@"
  fi
}
```

This avoids [Bash Pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) (parsing the output of `ls` instead of using a shell glob) and uses the shell's `set` builtin to read matching filenames into the `$@` positional parameter array. This way, you can use `$#` to count the number of files unambiguously (even if they contain newlines - where piping `ls` to `wc` would give the wrong count), and there's no need to use a separate `find` command to obtain the matching names all over again.

If you want to display the filenames *without* the extension, you can replace `$@` in the `printf` with `${@%.*}` which removes the shortest trailing substring  matching `.*` from each element of the array using [parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion).

Although I chose to use a `(( ... ))` arithmetic construct to test the number of files, there's nothing wrong with using the POSIX `[ $# -le 10 ]` or `[ $# -lt 10 ]` if you prefer. The extra `$# > 0` test is just to keep the output pretty when there are no files of the given extension.

---

You could easily extend the function to accept multiple extensions by using an array for the extensions:

```
function report {
  shopt -s nullglob
  local exts=( "$@" )
  for ext in "${exts[@]}"; do 
    set -- *."$ext"
    printf 'There are %d %s files' $# "$ext"
    if (( $# > 0 && $# < 10 )); then
      printf ': \n' 
      printf '\t%s\n' "$@"
    else
      printf '.\n'
    fi
  done
}
```

Example usage:

```
$ report txt jpg foo
There are 71 txt files.
There are 4 jpg files: 
    b.jpg
    foo.jpg
    inv_logpolar.jpg
    logpolar.jpg
There are 0 foo files.
```